# How to get a local copy of a website from a hosting site?

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting

I'm redesigning a website and I need to have a local copy from the hosting service but it doesn't show where to 'fork' a website? I can't even tell if it's on wordpress or not? I'm new to this so any input would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to need to use the services cPanel then file manager if it has one.

Another option would be to SFTP or FTP into the hosting and pull the files via a client like [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/).

Or if you have SSH access you can sFTP or add it to a private repository via the CLI.

With all the options you will need to have server access.

Comment: I don't see any file manager option but there is an ftp user. so I should run the filezilla service and pull it from the hostingwebsite?

Comment: yep, and then if there is a database use phpMyAdmin panel the service provides.

Comment: I have to download the database as well?

Comment: maybe, most definitely if it uses a framework as most are database driven.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download all files using FTP/SFTP
2. Export MySQL database using PhpMyAdmin (usually available from CPanel)
3. Extract files to your local server's Apache root directory (E.g. C:\xampp\htdocs)
4. Import the database using e.g. http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
5. In wp_options table update 'home' and 'siteurl' values to represent your localhost url.

if you're on Wordpress you can use a tool like [Wp Clone](https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/)